# Using a line as a node in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

is there a syntax that allows using a line as a node in tikz? In the following example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %dummy nodes
    \node (A) at (0,0) {};
    \node (B) at (5,0) {};
    \node (C) at (2,-5) {};
        \draw (A)--(B);
        \draw (C)--(2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to write something such as `\draw (C)--[(A)--(B)]` instead of `\draw (C)--(2,0)`. Of course in this example I know the nodes' coordinates explicitly, but in my actual diagram I don't, and whenever I add something that changes the size of it, I have to trial-and-error adjust the coordinate of the explicit node.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain better what is your problem?

Comment: Yes: I would like to draw a line from the node C to its orthogonal projection on the line (A)--(B), and I was hoping that there were a straight forward synthax to accomplish that.

Comment: Yes the syntax can be found on this site by searching for "tikz orthogonal line" e.g. here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19349/8650

Comment: @hpekristiansen : Yes, that works as well. I prefer muzimuzhi's solution in the present case, but this will come in handy. (didn't search deeply enough apparently)

Comment: tkz euclide has  built in ortho support -- see here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/559266/197451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option `local bounding box=<node name>` is what you need here.

```
\documentclass{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %dummy nodes
    \node (A) at (0,0) {};
    \node (B) at (5,0) {};
    \node (C) at (2,-5) {};
        % this creates a rectangle node named AB
        \draw[local bounding box=AB] (A)--(B);
        \draw (C) |- (AB);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Update:** And a projection modifier version:

```
\documentclass{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %dummy nodes
    \node (A) at (0,0) {};
    \node (B) at (5,0) {};
    \node (C) at (2,-5) {};
        \draw (A)--(B);
        % draw a line from node C to the projection of C on line A to B
        % see pgfmanual, sec. 13.5.5 _The Syntax of Projection Modifiers_
        \draw (C) |- ($(A)!(C)!(B)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works very well. I might add that this solution produces a path between A,B and C, which is fine given the question that I asked. But this will look messy with dashed or dotted lines (which was in fact my purpose), and so - I as sensed -  hpekristiansen's link ended up being useful here (solution that I went for in the end). Hope that helps future readers.

Comment: * I meant "an L-shaped path between A, C's projection on AB, and C."

Comment: @Mogu To make my answer more helpful for future readers, I've added another example using projection as mentioned by hpekristiansen. Thanks for your comments.